# GRASS GIS: r.out.gdal raises an exception and hangs if it's called multiple consecutive times

Tags: grass-gis, python-3, grass.script, pygrass

I'm using a small python routine (grass.script, pygrass) to handle several operations on sentinel2 imagery. I'm calling `r.out.gdal` inside the script and a very annoying problem occurs: when it is called multiple times (performing the exportation of several rasters) it raises an exception and hangs.

I've done several tests to check if the problem lies in my implementation, but the results tell the contrary: the hanging happens randomly at different points of the execution for the different tests (for some tests it manages to write all the maps but hangs instead of proceeding to the following operations, for some other runs of the same test script it only managed to write 2 or 3 maps and hanged). I then tried to use python `time.sleep()` and the results got better: it managed to conclude the operations for several runs, but sill hanged for 2/3 runs (using the same small testing script).

I'm pasting the text of the exception below.

Does anybody know why it happens and how to deal with the issue?

> r.out.gdal complete. File
> </Volumes/Maxtor/GISDBASE_histogram_analysis/clipped_maps_sectors/sentinel/20190223/rhow_20190223_B01_southern_wetlands_sector.tif>
> created. Checking GDAL data type and nodata value... Exception in
> thread Thread-1 : Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Applications/GRASS-7.8.app/Contents/Resources/lib/p
> ython3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>
> self.run()   File
> "/Applications/GRASS-7.8.app/Contents/Resources/gui/w
> xpython/core/gconsole.py", line 162, in run
>
> self.resultQ.put((requestId, self.requestCmd.run()))   File
> "/Applications/GRASS-7.8.app/Contents/Resources/gui/w
> xpython/core/gcmd.py", line 603, in run
>
> self._redirect_stream()   File
> "/Applications/GRASS-7.8.app/Contents/Resources/gui/w
> xpython/core/gcmd.py", line 632, in _redirect_stream
>
> self.stderr.write(line)   File
> "/Applications/GRASS-7.8.app/Contents/Resources/gui/w
> xpython/core/gconsole.py", line 299, in write
>
> value = int(line.rsplit(':', 1)[1].strip()) IndexError : list index
> out of range

Comment: May the index error, that you receive, lead to this problem?

Comment: The thing is that the index it's mentioning is in the GRASS built in scripts/functions and I don't have the competence for twiddling in their scripts to look for the problem. I don't know how to use the information about the index error to retrieve the reason of the problem, also because, as I mentioned, it happens at random points of the execution, so I really don't understand what triggers it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? I can try the reproduce the error. I have just seen this https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/866. Smilar error for another grass tool

Comment: Yes, sure: I'll post a google drive link to the script in few moments. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: This is the link to the script that first caused the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DuYGcFYAd-3Cyn830mwrWMZaW6TyP6Wr/view?usp=sharing
I run it on a set of 9 scenes. If you need them I can share with you the data I used and the files with the boundaries for the raster clipping.
You can reproduce the error by just calling `r.out.gdal` n (like 5, but 3 is also enough to raise the issue for me) consecutive times within a super small routine run in a mapset with some raster data. It occurs also outside of a loop, I'll send you also the few lines I used for the testing asap

Comment: Here's the essential lines for the issue raising: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMzmeP8fBuGPxyh3JBTw3PAopDwsaY5F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue only occurs if you run the script from the GUI, if you run it from shell it does not hang. At this point I think that the cause must be a bug within the GUI (probably the same of the link you sent above). Does it happen to you too?

Comment: Yes, it sounds really alike the bug report in the link. You may consider posting your problem there too. Hope it will resolve soon.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll surely post the issue there too. Luckily it's a non major issue and it can be quite easily bypassed by just running the scripts from the shell instead of using the GUI.